# Is Filemaker suitable for an EMR?

Tags: filemaker

A medical practice has approached us about using Filemaker as a fully-fledged EMR system with a HEAVY emphasis on using iPads to enter patient records, photos, digital signatures etc which can obviously be accessed on desktops as well. Ultimately they would like such a system to replace their current EMR and takeover all billing operations, patient scheduling and so forth. They only use Macs in their practice.

We have very little experience with Filemaker but found [this](http://goo.gl/z0wsZ) discussing the Pros and Cons of it however it seems that Filemaker has come a long way since 2009 when that question was asked...

So overall I'm just trying to work out if Filemaker is suitable for such an application or what would be the pros and cons of using a combination of FMP12 and FM Go.

(Sorry if I've done anything wrong - first question...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a FileMaker Developer myself, I would say go for it. I agree with Mikhail - You WILL see results faster than any other platform. You can make changes yourself easily and live or you can get a FileMaker developer - just like you would need to get a developer for any application.

With an off-the-shelf application, they tend to be quite inflexible, however I am sure there are systems out there that allow some customisation.

FileMaker is a very capable product. We have written many applications for vertical markets, such as law firms and even a Harley Street plastic surgeon who gathers patient data on an iPad and even sketches the suggested surgery on a picture of the patient.

For those who think FileMaker is a baby, have a look at http://www.businessmancrm.com - this is a full ERP system used all over the world. This is not an advert, but a demonstration of what is possible with FileMaker.

Dollar for dollar, FileMaker will win hands down... and when it comes to time frames, there is no contest. We are open minded - We constantly look for other products to develop applications for ourselves and customers and we have not found anything more viable just yet.

Pros:

- Extremely quick environment
- Cross platform
- Integrate other SQL data sources into application
- ODBC Support
- Remote Access
- Can be run from a USB stick if needed!
- Thousands of developers around the world
- Large community
- FileMaker Inc. have made a profit every single quarter since existence, therefore are stable and do have the backing of Apple!
- Reasonable Cost
- Make changes yourself
- Easy to backup, supports incremental backup
- Easy to secure and encrypt data on a network
- Supports terminal server
- FMGo is free

Cons

- High level language (not low level with layout object control) - However does support plugins
- Requires FileMaker client (unless a web application/interface is built in PHP or using IWP - Instant Web Publishing)
- Proprietary Database (however can easily link into MySQL, MSSQL and Oracle)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, not worth it.
It's a very clunky front-end for a database.

If you do decide to pick it up your basically stuck with paying a Filemaker developer for the rest of its existence.

One of my clients at the moment has had it for the last ~6+? years after only being with them for the last 8 months i'm trying very hard to push them away from it and onto a newer system.

I can suggest looking at Mastercare EMR, Profile and MMEX.

Comment: Of those suggestions it just seems like the iPad functionality isn't quite there yet and without that the practice really has no reason to move from their existing EMR. In fact the only reason Filemaker popped up as a viable option is because of its iPad functionality. Basically, it's "this works exactly how we want it on an iPad" or nothing for them...

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker is perfectly capable of it, of course, and I expect you'll be getting first results much faster than with any other approach, especially with the iPad. There's quite a few EMRs out there written in FileMaker. There are downsides, of course; it was always targeted to end users so it ended up fairly inconventional from a common programmer's point of view. Many programmers dislike this. Being end-user it suffers from many simplifications (well, not exactly suffers, actually; this makes development faster as there's fewer choices), but people always want something special so there's a huge number of workarounds to overcome these simplifications. These workarounds vary from relatively harmless to very hairy ones.

For example, to sign documents on iPad you need to add a webviewer control pointed to a generated HTML page via the "data:" protocol. The page is going to have a JavaScript that captures user's touches, paints them on a canvas, and serializes this into a string. Later a script will capture the string, store it in a FileMaker field, and change the generated HTML to use this string so the JavaScript can redraw the signature. This one is relatively simple and since the functionality cannot be obtained in any other way, it's in wide use; there's even a commercial module for around $300. A complex app may consists of dozens of such workarounds; anyone who is not a FileMaker developer won't be able to understand why you need a webviewer to capture a signature or why you use [a strange contraption of invisible tabs to display what looks like a simple pop-up list](http://www.teamdf.com/weetbicks/cool-things-to-do-with-tab-controls-in-filemaker-12/151/). I.e. it's not like you read a book and work from there; be ready to read quite a few blogs and frequent forums and mailing lists.

That said, it's a good product nonetheless with unique capabilities (that iPhone/iPad client, for one); paired with a good developer it can be very powerful.

Comment: Thanks! A great answer but Jamie's felt more specific to our application.

Answer (score 0):

Having developed an EMR system at a recent position for 3 years, I can tell you from experience that the requirements for a true EMR system may quickly outgrow the scope of what is easy to do in FileMaker.  A few really big, important EMR features come to mind immediately:

Insurance Eligibility verification: is there going to be a way to hit all of the major payers' web services or a third party aggregator to verify insurance eligibility from the iPad?

Insurance Card OCR: sure you can snap a photo of an insurance card, but now you have back office staff typing that information in from an image.  We implemented OCR of insurance cards in our EMR and it was a huge cost and time saver.

Security / Privacy concerns: HIPAA compliance is a big deal, and is FileMaker suitably transparent to be compliant?  Is there any way to audit who looks at a record?  How is the data transferred across the wire?

E-prescribing: All modern EMR's support electronic prescriptions, which carries a complex set of rules and implementation details along with it, I would want to be certain FileMaker could be integrated with an e-prescribing gateway before proceeding.

My main concern with using any off the shelf, cross platform tool to approach a problem as big and complex as an EMR would be getting painted into a corner down the road, having invested a bunch of time and money into a solution that may leave you unable to implement a feature or requirement, whereas paying the up front price of developing a native iOS app (and web apps and whatever else you need to integrate with) would eliminate that possibility, but obviously cost more.